Why can't SafeHandle be disposed manually by default?
Here is a simple example:

    public class SafeHandleSpike
    {
        [Test]
        // will fail
        public void Fake()
        {
            var i1 = IO.Fake.Counter;
            using (var obj = new Fake(true))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(i1, IO.Fake.Counter);
                // do things
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(i1 + 1, IO.Fake.Counter);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Real()
        {
            var i1 = IO.Real.Counter;
            using (var obj = new Real(true))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(i1, IO.Real.Counter);
                // do things
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(i1 + 1, IO.Real.Counter);
        }
    }

    public class Fake : SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public static volatile int Counter;

        public Fake(nint handle, bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
        {
            SetHandle(handle);
        }

        public Fake(bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            Counter += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Real : ActuallySafeHandle
    {
        public static volatile int Counter;

        public Real(bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ActualReleaseHandle()
        {
            Counter += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }


    public abstract class ActuallySafeHandle : SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public ActuallySafeHandle(bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
        {
        }


        public ActuallySafeHandle() : base(true)
        {
        }

        private static readonly IntPtr InvalidHandleValue = new(-1);
        public override bool IsInvalid => handle == InvalidHandleValue;

        protected abstract bool ActualReleaseHandle();


        protected sealed override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            if (!IsInvalid) return ActualReleaseHandle();

            return false;
        }

        protected new void Dispose()
        {
            ActualReleaseHandle();
        }

        protected sealed override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            ActualReleaseHandle();
        }
    }

When running the test, only the second test will succeed, the using in the first test will call the Dispose() function and do nothing, despite that Fake is already declared an IDisposable. I wasn't able to observe if GC can invoke it.
Why is it an IDisposable if the Dispose() function is useless?

Why does the Real test reference IO.Fake.Counter?

sorry that was a typo in copy-paste, corrected now, thank you so much!

In the documentation for SafeHandle Dispose it states that you want Dispose to be called before the last instance of the handle is released. Worst case the release will be triggered by the finalizer. Dispose releases the resources used by the safehandle implementation, Release serves to release the handle itself. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dispose?view=net-8.0)

Normally, ReleaseHandle is only called if your handle is valid. You bypass that expected behaviour on ActuallySafeHandle by overriding Dispose, suppressing the existing implementation. That's a bad idea. Don't override Dispose on safe handles.

well the UnsafeHandle is valid but useless, how to improve on top of it?

What do you mean, useless? Dispose()'s purpose is to free unmanaged resources. If the handle is invalid, it means it owns no resource, so there's nothing to free. It's okay if Dispose() does nothing in that case. What do you use safe handles for?

@EtiennedeMartel the Counter += 1; part actually represents cleanup of a serial port, the using block never close it properly and it leaks

Then don't inherit from safe handle? That's for wrapping operating system handles. Just make a regular class implement IDisposable and do what you need to do in Dispose().

One of the lines in the Dispose logic for SafeHandle is
performRelease = ((oldState & (StateBits.RefCount | StateBits.Closed)) == StateBits.RefCountOne) &&
                 _ownsHandle &&
                 !IsInvalid;

and then
if (performRelease)
{
.....
    ReleaseHandle();

So ReleaseHandle is only called if IsInvalid property returns false. But you are inheriting from SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid, which overrides IsInvalid and returns rather obviously false in the case the handle is -1.
Then, since you aren't passing a valid handle in the constructor, it will always be invalid and therefore ReleaseHandle will never be called. This is by design.
Your mistake is in the ActuallySafeHandle, which isn't safe at all. You are overriding Dispose, and therefore dangerously messing up all the logic for the reference counting and thread-safety. Do not do this. SafeHandle works perfectly fine if you give it a valid handle, it's up to you to define what that valid handle is. SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid is simply a shortcut to defining that.
So you would need a constructor that can create a SafeHandle with a IntPtr/nint handle value. Normally this is done automatically by the PInvoke marshaller, but you can also do it from a constructor.
public class Fake : SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    public static volatile int Counter;

    public Fake(nint handle, bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
    {
        base.SetHandle(handle);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        Counter += 1;
        return true;
    }
}

Also, note the actual purpose of SafeHandle. It's not necessary to use it just to create an IDisposable. It's specifically designed for thread-safe cleanup of OS handles, such as file, socket or kernel handles, and only where you actually have the native handle, not a managed object which holds it. The idea is: instead of passing or returning an IntPtr in PInvoke, instead you pass around a SafeHandle, which the marshaller understands and will ensure it's not disposed early. It's not intended for generalized usage.

thanks a lot, do you have a full example that can make the using block working as intended?

See new edit...

thank you so much, but still doesn't work (On C# 9.0, Unity 2022), will update my question to be on par with your changes tho

Your test code hasn't changed, you still have using (var obj = new Fake(true)) which isn't creating a valid handle. You'd need something like using (var obj = new Fake(InsertValidHandleHere, true))
